# verify file name at upload with only a given file name

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

How can i verify a file name when uploading  e.g. xyz.xlsx for this specific file and no other? Thus the file is uploaded if and only if its name is xyz with extension xlsx "xyz.xlsx".

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what your looking for, just grab the filename and test it.

Example:
`if($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'] == "xyz.xlsx")`

Comment: Thanks a lot MrGlass for that

Answer (score 1):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

When you do an upload with PHP, you get a $_FILES array (kind of like $_POST). You'll find the original filename in $_FILES['userfile']['name']. You can verify that as MyGlass suggests in his answer.

```
if($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'] == "xyz.xlsx")
```

Additionally, codeignitor provides a file upload class that can be used to eliminate some of the boiler plate of file uploads here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Use $this->upload->data() to get the array with the filename info (the key is 'file_name').

```
$data = $this->upload->data();
if($data['file_name'] == "xyz.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it does check for file name not right, how can i delete the file if its not the expected

Comment: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php -- unlink is the function you're looking for

Comment: if you didn't copy the file from the temp location, then it won't be saved anyway. If you did copy it to the final location, then you'll need to use unlink to get rid of it.